# Opening submenu correctly in jQuery

Tags: jquery

I'm somewhat new to jQuery, and I try to create a mobile menu with submenus which open on "click" event.

My problem is:
There are more elements with the "tile" class that have a submenu, and obviously I only want to display the submenu of that one I actually clicked on (not all of them as it happens now).

I tried this, but it opens the submenu of all ".tile" elements:

```
$(".tile").on("click", function () {
    $(".tile ul").css("display", "block");
});
```

How should I correct this to display only the correct ".tile ul"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@TusharGupta has a good answer (i upvoted it), so long as you dont have multiple submenus. if you do, then use this:

```
$(".tile").on("click", function () {
    $(this).children('ul').css({display:'block'});
});
```

This only opens direct children of the item, rather than all children. Otherwise, the use of `.find()` is preferred as it is the most performant.

Answer (score 2):

Use [this keyword](http://learn.jquery.com/javascript-101/this-keyword/)

```
$(".tile").on("click", function () {
    $(this).find('ul').css("display", "block");
});
```

or

Use [.show()](http://api.jquery.com/show/)

```
$(".tile").on("click", function () {
    $(this).find('ul').show();
});
```

`this` keyword refers the current element .